# How to sort table column as number? (only javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, html-table

I need to sort this table but Percentage and Numbers columns are sorting in a strange way. It's sorting them as strings, not numbers.
I googled a lot and tried to use parseInt, parseFloat and number but the code below is the best I could get.

Any way I could convert only these columns (and not the name column) to numbers?

Sorry if it's too noob of a question, I'm a beginner in coding. :-/

```js
var tabela, asc1 = 1, asc2 = 1, asc3 = 1;

window.onload = function() {
  
  tabela = document.getElementById("table");
  
}


function sort_table(tbody,col,asc) {
  var rows = tbody.rows,
      rlen = rows.length,
      arr = new Array(),
      i, j, cells, clen;
  
  for (i=0 ; i<rlen ; i++){
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    clen = cells.length;
    arr[i] = new Array;
    for( j=0; j<clen ; j++){
      
      
      arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
      
    }
    
  }

  arr.sort( function(a, b){
    return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1 * asc);
  });
  for (i=0; i<rlen ; i++){
    rows[i].innerHTML = "<td>" + arr[i].join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <th onclick="sort_table(table,0,asc1);asc1 *= -1;asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1;">Number</th>
          <th onclick="sort_table(table,1,asc2);asc2 *= -1;asc1 = 1; asc3 = 1;">Name</th>
          <th onclick="sort_table(table,2,asc3);asc3 *= -1;asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1;">Percentage</th>
           
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table">
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>10%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>55%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>3%</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: use this ->    arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML / 1;

Comment: Thank you @ZivWeissman  That works but the Name column returns NaN. It needs to be sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sortVal = cells[j].innerHTML;
arr[i][j] = isNaN(sortVal) ? sortVal : sortVal/1;
```